# How to make an L7 tank gun eject with more force

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms, firearms

I'm looking into tank autoloaders, and something that eludes me is how modern tank guns eject. I know there is a pair of "ears" that push against the case rim, but the precise mechanism eludes me.

I also know that there were autoloading designs using both Rh 120 and L7 pattern that ejected with much more force, for example the M1 TTB for the Rh 120 and the M1128 for rhe L7.

So my question is how exactly does the ejection cycle of these guns work, and how can it be altered for a more forceful ejection?

I hope my question makes sense. Thank you for your time!

Comment: If you can link to a diagram of one of these auto loader mechanisms we can suggest how you might increase the ejection force.

Comment: @Drew Thank you! My question was actually more about ejecting from the gun itself, but I would love your help nevertheless. [The M1 TTB autoloader](https://f001.backblazeb2.com/file/Soapbox-Photos/ttb+autoloader.jpg) would be one such machine I would love to draw inspiration from, and I do not know how that ejects (though I know it does, given the [ejection port on the back](https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-d4c0008f4b7e0dd8b4cd7250effc0bfb-c)). Here's an [animation of its operation](https://youtu.be/CGj2qBQRKoE?t=256) which, however, doesn't show ejection.

Comment: Well I can't say for sure but my guess is that at the end of the recoil stroke some type of lever is engaged that grabs the case and pushes it out of the chamber (like on a regular manually loaded artillery piece). By changing the geometry of that mechanism, you can change how fast it pushes the case. Again, that's just a guess, I don't know much about these guns.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the additional information that you provided in your comment.

Comment: Thank you, I will. It occurs to me that I should be more clear on which part of the ejection cycle I am interested in.